# Class extending AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter text gets cut off

Tags: android-layout, android-tv, leanback

I'm using a class extending AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter. The summary text is relatively long. For some reason the text gets cut off after a certain length. I could not figure out how to display the entire text without it being cut off.
I tried `viewHolder.getBody().setLines(20);` and other property changes but nothing seemed to have the desired effect.

This it the Presenter class I'm using:

```
public class MovieDetailPresenter extends AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter {

@Override
protected void onBindDescription(ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
    Video video = (Video) item;

    if (video != null) {
        viewHolder.getTitle().setText(video.title);
        viewHolder.getSubtitle().setText(video.subtitle);
        viewHolder.getBody().setText(video.summary);

    }
  }
}
```

How can I remove the text length limit/cutting off?

Here a picture to better illustrate what I mean. The text at the bottom right isn't displayed in its full length but gets cut off and adds three dots (...) at the end.

[image]

Thanks for any hints/help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution: Making a custom “AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter” without the `addPreDrawListener()` method (which is causing the problem) and use it in the “DetailsDescriptionPresenter”.

Answer (score 0):

`body.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` should do the trick unless you are forcing a specific height somewhere in your LayoutParams. I assume you're setting height to wrap_content? You could try enabling `Show Layout Bounds` in the developer options to see if your changes have any effect.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I found a solution by cloning the AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter class and removing the addPreDrawListener() method from the class which prevented me from making layout changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove ellipsis for every AbstractDetailsDescriptionPresenter instance, you can configure new resource `integer.xml` and add entry `lb_details_description_body_max_lines` that will define maximum number of lines. I'm using min SDK 28.

Example of `integer.xml` resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="lb_details_description_body_max_lines">128</integer>
</resources>
```